# Getting nullpointerexception while displaying in edittext

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, nullpointerexception

In Android When I parse the json data I get the object and can be seen in the logcat.but when I convert to JSONArray and then to getString() it gives NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION.
I want to display this json in my edittext please help 
please can anyone help me .

This is my json result form php

```
{"result":[{"uid":"1","name":"vipul","phone":"9772950005","sap":"500023675"}],"success":1}
```

Note: I am getting json its just the problem how to get that element and display it.

this is my json that can be seen in logcat

```
10-19 02:13:51.082: W/Trace(1267): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 02:13:51.152: D/This is json error(1267): {"success":1,"result":[{"uid":"1","sap":"500023675","phone":"9772950005","name":"vipul"}]}
```

my java code is ::::::java code:::::

```
      public class search_view extends Activity{    
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONObject result;
private static final String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_RESULT = "result";
private static final String TAG_UID = "uid";
private static final String TAG_SAP = "sap";
public String sap="500023675";
EditText txtName,txtsap,txtPhone,txtuid;

      JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
      private static final String KEY_SEARCH_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android/search.php";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);
        txtsap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sap);
        txtsap.setText("This is onCreate");
        new searchall().execute();
}

class searchall extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{
    JSONObject json;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(search_view.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Searching... be patient..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        JSONArray resu;
        String id = "hello this is null";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            resu=result.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            resu = null;
        }   

        for( int i = 0;i <= resu.length(); i++){try {
            id = resu.getString(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

                txtuid =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uid);
                txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                txtPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
                txtsap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sap);
                txtuid.setText(id);
                txtName.setText(id);
                txtPhone.setText("phone");
                txtsap.setText("this is yes");





        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int success;                    
                    List<NameValuePair> lis = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    lis.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sap", sap));
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(KEY_SEARCH_URL, "GET", lis);
                    Log.d("This is json error", json.toString());
                    try {
                        success = json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONObject res = null;
                    try {
                        res = json.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULT);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //obj = (JSONObject) res.get(j);
                return res;



}
}
}
```

also I am using AsyncTask and changing main UI on onPostExecute()

The problem is I am not able to display it

here is my::::::::::::::: LOG CAT:::::::::::;;

```
    10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.god.upesgetall.search_view$searchall.onPostExecute(search_view.java:73)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.god.upesgetall.search_view$searchall.onPostExecute(search_view.java:1)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-19 02:13:54.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Please Help....

Comment: `for( int i = 0;i <= resu.length(); i++)` -- replace `<=` with `<`.

Comment: @lealand I tried replacing   <= with < still the same problem I guess there is some problem with how I am fetching the JSON..

Comment: What's on line 73 then? We can only guess without knowing what's on the line where the null pointer exception is raised. Also, if `resu.getString(i)` returns `null` then all your `(R.id.*)` lines will fail. Just check to make sure `id != null` first.

Comment: @lealand this is on line 73 
    resu=result.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

Comment: Then that means that `result` is null. I see that you also have an instance variable `result`. Which one are you intending to be dealing with? Because right now, it's the variable passed in `onPostExecute(JSONObject result)`. It's not a good idea to shadow instance variables.

Comment: Give me the link for your JSON jar? Couldn't find it

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan by JSON jar exactly what do you mean? my jar file or my JSONparser class

Comment: @lealand I want to deal with the result I passesd from doInBackground as it contains my JSONObject..

Comment: Use `this.result`. But seriously, don't name variables that are declared outside of methods (known as instance variables or fields) with the same names as variables which are passed with method calls as parameters. Follow this rule in any programming language to avoid bugs like this.

Comment: Also, don't use the name `resu` because you couldn't name it `result`. This is not informative and equally error prone. Call it `tagResult` because that's exactly what it contains.

Comment: @lealand Thank you .this solved my problem ..I would follow the guidelines by you . would not name them same.

Comment: It's typical to append an underscore (i.e. `result_`) to make it clear that this is a field variable. There are also style guides that you should read over. [This is the offical android one](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html). Many companies, [like Google](https://code.google.com/p/java-coding-standards/wiki/Introduction) also publish their standards. Good to hear your problem is solved!

Comment: @lealand please could you send the correct java code ..ie with whatever editing is needed :).. could you like answer it .

Comment: No, this is not a code writing service. You're on the right track. Just write small pieces of code at a time and constantly test. I never write more than maybe 20 lines at a time without running and testing. If things fail, then I always know where things went wrong.